# Skip Me.FormClosing

Tags: vb.net, formclosing

i've set a warning message before closing the form, but is there a way to skip it sometimes?

My code:

```
Sub Me_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel the installation?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        e.Cancel = False
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

but i have a final code that must close the app without this message:

```
Private Sub Done_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Done.Click
    'need to close without warning
    Close()
End Sub
```

can you help me change this or add something that allows that button to close the form without launching `Me.FormClosing`?

Comment: Use a module level flag or perhaps the `CloseReason`.  A simple `isDone` flag would seem to suffice.  The message is actually related to whether the task is done or not; not whether the form is closing.

Comment: @Plutonix i'm not finding a way to write isdone at somewhere, VS shows errors wherever i write it

Comment: `Private IsDone As Boolean = False`  set it to true when done then evaluate in formclosing.  You may want (need!) to learn about [Scope in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Boolean` flag to determine the installation status (success or fail/abort)

```
Private installSuccess As Boolean ' False by default.

Private Sub Install()

    Try 
        ' Installer logic here
        ' ...

        Me.installSuccess = True

    Catch ' ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Then:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) _
Handles MyBase.FormClosing

    If Me.installSuccess Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel the installation?", "Warning", 
                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                       MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        e.Cancel = False

    Else
        e.Cancel = True

    End If

End Sub
```